# Product of integrable functions also integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I can't find in any book on measure and integral whether a product of two Lebesgue integrable functions is also integrable. Could someone clarify for me under what circumstances it is true?

To be specific, I have an assumption $fg\in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1 (\Omega)$ and I want to determine what requirements on $f$ a $g$ are sufficient to hold this assumption.

Comment: The most standard assumption that will imply this is that $f$ and $g$  are both in $L_{loc}^2(\Omega)$.  You can prove the sufficiency of this assumption by applying Cauchy-Schwarz to $fg1_K$ where $K$ is a compact set.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thank you, that should help. Could you give me an advice what to do if I have the assumption $fg\in L^{1+\eta}(\Omega), \eta>0$? I cannot use the Hölder's inequality now, can I?